# Web View using android download manager to download files

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-download-manager

I have been working on an android application that uses web view to view web pages from a website. but this website has video and audio files. Anytime the user clicks the website download button for a video/audio it opens the default android browser of the phone. I would love my application to handle the downloading itself, i researched on download manager for android but could not get it to work. how can i implement the download manager to listen for download clicks from the website and handle the download, save it to a specified directory without calling the phone browser?

Here's my code for the activity that has the web view, editing my code to answer will be more preferable.

```
    package com.akinlawongroup.JWBroadcastApp;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class DrawerActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

        private WebView mWebView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
            drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://tv.jw.org/#en/video");


    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.d("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode + " - " + description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // handle different requests for different type of files
            // this example handles downloads requests for .apk and .mp3 files
            // everything else the webview can handle normally
            if (url.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
                // Make a new request pointing to the .apk url
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
                // appears the same in Notification bar while downloading
                request.setDescription("Description for the DownloadManager Bar");
                request.setTitle("JWVideo.mp4");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }
                // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "JWVideo.mp4");
                // get download service and enqueue file
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(request);
            }
            // if there is a link to anything else than .apk or .mp3 load the URL in the webview
            else view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
}



            // getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sub, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            // if (id==R.id.navigate){
            //     startActivity(new Intent(this, SubActivity.class));
            // }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: None of your current code shows what you've tried already to trap the users interaction with the web view. Maybe if you could show what you've already tried the community will be able to help more

Comment: @Flexicoder I just edited the question and the code. But the app still crashes on clicking download. What am i missing.

Answer (score 0):

To download, try this:

```
wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps!